# For the Dynkin $\pi-\lambda$ lemma, how can it show that a CDF is uniquely determine by its probability distribution?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I read a post here that gave an outline of the proof that one can use the pi-lambda lemma to determine a CDF completely:

[Stats Stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78912/how-would-one-use-the-pi-lambda-theorem-in-determining-that-a-cdf-completely-def)

However, I do not understand the main idea of what is going on. For example, they say that "Sets of this form are a $\pi$-system, so the $\sigma$-algebra they generate is equal to the $\lambda$ system they generate". Is this just a direct result of the pi-lambda lemma? I am also confused why showing that our system having a certain $\sigma$-algebra can help you determine your CDF. Does anyone have any insights? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstood the statement. It is not about complete determinacy of a CDF, but about that of a distribution. So let me repeat the correct statement:

> A probability distribution on $\mathbb R$ is completely determined by its cumulative distribution function.

This is indeed a direct result of $\pi-\lambda$ theorem, as it is explained in the answer you refer to.

Other way around, the uniqueness of CDF for a distribution is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Answer on your first question.

Let $\mathcal A$ be a collection of subsets of some set.

It generates a $\sigma$-algebra, denoted by $\sigma(\mathcal A)$ and also generates a Dynkin-system, denoted by $\lambda(\mathcal A)$.

Every $\sigma$-algebra is a Dynkin-system so that $\lambda(\mathcal A)\subseteq \sigma(\mathcal A)$.

If $\mathcal A$ is a $\pi$-system (i.e. is closed under finite intersections) then the [$\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system#Dynkin.27s_.CF.80-.CE.BB_theorem) tells us that $\sigma(\mathcal A)$ is a subcollection of any Dynkin-system that contains $\mathcal A$, so we conclude that $\sigma(\mathcal A)\subseteq \lambda(\mathcal A)$.

Final result of this: $\sigma(\mathcal A)=\lambda(\mathcal A)$ if $\mathcal A$ is a $\pi$-system.

---

Answer on your second question.

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are random variables.

It is not difficult to prove that the collection $\mathcal D:=\{A\in\mathcal B\mid P(X\in A)=P(Y\in A)\}$ is a Dynkin-system on set $\mathbb R$.

Here $\mathcal B$ is a notation for the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R$. By definition it is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by open sets, but it can be proved that $\mathcal B=\sigma(\mathcal A)$ where $\mathcal A:=\{(a,b]\mid a\leq b\}$.

Now assume that they have the same CDF $F$.

Then $P(X\in(a,b])=F(b)-F(a)=P(Y\in(a,b])$ so we conclude that collection $\mathcal A$ is a subcollection of $\mathcal D$.

Now realize that $\mathcal A$ is a $\pi$-system. Then $\mathcal B=\sigma(\mathcal A)=\lambda(\mathcal A)\subseteq\mathcal D$ proving that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution.

Comment: They say that the $\lambda$ system is is a collection of subsets of $\Omega$. In the case of the half open interval, $(-\infty, b]$, do you know what would be the $\lambda$ system there?

Comment: I left out $\Omega$ and it handles about a Dynkinsystem on $\mathbb R$